# Mongo not always returning correct results

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a nodeJS script that is processing queued JSON requests. We query Mongo (  v3.6.3 ) for a queue of requests to process and then perform a forEach on the queue. We query our API endpoint using promises and async / await to parse the request.

We perform a Mongo query to see if we have an existing record for the patient over the past 3 days. We look for the patient Id and pharmacy Id using findOne or find limit 1 ( have tried both in an attempt to resolve issue ) . If we have an existing record, we perform updates on the existing record. Otherwise, we create a new document. This appears to work most of the time. However, sometimes each queued entry will result in the creation a new document. So if we have 4 entires in the queue for a patient we will create 4 encounters. We can clear the database and process the queue again, and it will work correctly. It appears to work the vast majority of the time. The process can begin working and then shortly after starting start to break. Once we create one duplicate record, all other items in the queue end up being created as new entries.

I think the issue is related to Mongo not returning data correctly. Has anyone witnessed anything like this ?

We recently switched to find and limit 1 to see if that helps. We have processed the queue various times and the codes works and does not results in duplicates. We noticed the duplicates seem to happen when we process the first queue of the day. But the first queue of the day does not always result in an error. However, this may and likely is a coincidence.

How we query and process the queue

```
  let token;
  (async () => {
    // Get Access Token
    token = await authenticate();

        PharmacyQueue.find({ $and: [{ archive: false }, { date: { $gte: today } }] })
      .then(results => {
        let queue = [];
        results.forEach(request => {
          queue.push(JSON.parse(request.rawJSON));
          request.archive = true;
          request.save().catch(err => {
            console.log('Unable to archive');
          });
        });

        return queue;
      })
      .then(async requests => {
        for (const request of requests) {
          let response = await parseRequest(token, request);
          // SLEEP NOT NEEDED - JUST ADDED TO GIVE US TIME TO WATCH DEBUG LOGS
          await sleep(1000);
          console.log(response);
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        mongoose.disconnect();
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  })();
```

Code on the API to search for existing record - WHERE THE ISSUES OCCUR.
We just switched from findOne to find with limit of 1

```
 // Search For existing Encounter
  PharmacyEncounter.find(
    {
      $and: [
        {
          'patient.patientId': patient.patientId
        },
        {
          'pharmacy.ehrId': pharmacy.ehrId
        },
        {
          date: {
            $gt: threeDaysAgo
          }
        },
        {
          date: {
            $lte: moment(today)
              .endOf('day')
              .toDate() //today +'T23:59:59'
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    '-rawJSON -analytics'
  )
    .limit(1)
    .then(results => {
      if (
        results &&
        results[0] &&
        results[0].patient.patientId
      ) {
        console.log('Encounter Exists');
        // Encounter Already exists

        // Check if Prescription is already attached to encounter
        let desc = 'Appended medication';
        results[0].prescription.filter(presc => {
          if (presc.rxNumber == prescription.rxNumber) {
            // Existing Medication with same rxNumber found

            // Get remove index
            const removeIndex = results[0].prescription
              .map(item => item.rxNumber.toString())
              .indexOf(prescription.rxNumber);
            // Splice out of array
            results[0].prescription.splice(removeIndex, 1);
            desc = 'Updated medication';
          }
        });

        // Append Prescription ( updated or new )
        results[0].prescription.push(prescription);
        results[0]
          .save()
          .then(savedRx => {
            res.json({
              status: 'SUCCESS',
              id: savedRx._id,
              desc
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            const error = JSON.stringify(err);
            res.status(500).json({ status: 'ERROR', desc: error });
          });
      } else {
        // New Encounter - Create Encounter
        ... more code here to process new encounter ...
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The threeDaysAgo and today variables were constants contained outside of the request. So they were set immutable when the node application started. Mongo would return proper results until the next day. Then mongo would stop providing "correct" results. I would make a change to the code to test and nodemon restarted the server resolving the issue for another day.